# How to send a SOAP response of Client to Requested party

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap

I'm developing a Spring Boot application that is acting as a channel between 2 components. which consume SOAP Request and Produces SOAP Response.

eg :-

A -> calling party
B -> My Component
C -> client party.

A<->B<->C

Previously A and C are connecting to each other directly through SOAP operations. C party is using RPC encoded WSDL.

I have deployed the party C WSDL interface using the below code. As I need to forward the Request to C and Process Request from A.

Creating Endpoint using `@Endpoint` annotation as below and `@XPathParam` to read tag value.

I want to return that SOAP response to Party A. which is coming from Party C. But Cannot figure out how to return the SOAP response coming from C to A.

A hint would be helpful.

```java
@Bean
public Wsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition(){
  SimpleWsdl11Definition simpleWsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
  simpleWsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("/wsdl/calculator.wsdl"));
  return simpleWsdl11Definition;
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet>
  messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext){
  MessageDispatcherServlet messageDispatcherServlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
  messageDispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
  return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(messageDispatcherServlet, "/medium/ws/*");
}
```

```java
@ResponsePayload
@PayloadRoot(namespace = "http://medium.com/types/calculator", localPart = "AdditionInput")
public Output addition(@XPathParam("lineId") String lineID){
  // Calling Party C and creating Request Using Apache Axis tool for party C
  // String response = SOAP Response from Party C.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed Client WSDL as we are consuming request and forwarding this request to C.
So, I have created my one Object and Mapped value of C Response in Object. I have return that Object in Response . Using Interceptor, I have converted that Object to desired Response.